# Cannot implicitly convert type IEnumerable to IQueryable with Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am completely new to Entities (I've taken over another persons project) and therefore I am prolly missing some key facts but I'll try and explain my problem:

I have applicants who has a table with their information like first name etc. And I also have a table with the ASP.NET Users. The tables are linked by the user_id.

I am trying to make the login name a selectable listitem in a dropdown but in order to do so I need to join the two tables. I have written the following code:

```
var container = new ModelContainer();
var manager = new ApplicantDBManager();

IEnumerable<Business.Entities.EF.Applicant> applicantQuery;

if (txtSearch.Text.Equals(string.Empty))
{
    applicantQuery = container.Applicants;
}
else
{
    var ids = manager.ApplicantSearchForIDs(ddlSearch.SelectedValue, txtSearch.Text, chkIncludeInactive.Checked);

    applicantQuery = (from a in container.Applicants
                      join u in container.Users on a.user_id equals u.user_id
                      where ids.Contains(a.user_id)
                      select new
                      {
                          user_id = a.user_id,
                          first_name = a.first_name,
                          last_name = a.last_name,
                          login_name = u.login_name,
                          date_of_birth = a.date_of_birth,
                          kot_cpr = a.kot_cpr,
                          address = a.address,
                          email = a.email,
                          telephone_number = a.telephone_number,
                          citizenship = a.citizenship
                      });
}
```

I am getting an error like "Cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.Iqueryable to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable" and it seems not to matter how I try and fix it (I've tried adding .ToList().AsQueryable(), First() and such with no luck). I think it has something to do with the Applicant entity?

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure that isn't the *exact* error message you're getting - I suspect the exact error message would include the type arguments, indicating that the `IQueryable<T>` has an anonymous type argument, whereas it was trying to convert to an `IEnumerable<Business.Entities.EF.Applicant>`. These things are important: always copy and paste error messages *directly* into questions, to avoid losing important information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
select new 
{
    ...
}
```

That's creating an instance of an anonymous type. How do you expect that to create a `Business.Entities.EF.Applicant` object?

You may well *just* need to change your code to:

```
select new Business.Entities.EF.Applicant
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @ChristianHansenNørgaard: Why are you specifying a property which isn't part of `Applicant`, if the result is meant to be a sequence of `Applicant` results? Why not just remove that property... you're not going to be able to *use* it from the result anyway...

Comment: I think I'm not exactly getting how this works. I need the UserName from table aspnet_Users and this is why i am trying to join the 2 tables like a normal join query and i thought i could include it in my results so i could add i to a gridview along with all the applicants information.

Comment: @ChristianHansenNørgaard: Well put it this way - your query is currently an `IEnumerable<Applicant>`. Does that have all the information you need? If not, you need something else. (Think about the other side of the `if` - you only have the applicants there...)

Comment: I finally figured it out. I had to create a new class and change the correct query in a totally different file, not this one. Im starting to get the whole entity thing and it looks like the original programmers went code first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code. Change the code to

```
select new Business.Entities.EF.Applicant
{
user_id = a.user_id,
first_name = a.first_name,
last_name = a.last_name,
login_name = u.login_name,
date_of_birth = a.date_of_birth,
kot_cpr = a.kot_cpr,
address = a.address,
email = a.email,
telephone_number = a.telephone_number,
citizenship = a.citizenship
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`select new` returns anonymous type object whereas `applicantQuery` is of type  `Business.Entities.EF.Applicant`. So, like Jon Skeet said, return the object of the expected type.